# Is there a pattern using Linq to dynamically create a filter?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

Is there a pattern using Linq to dynamically create a filter?

I have the need to create custom filtering on a list, in the past I would just dynamically create the SQL...it doesn't seem like this is possible with Linq.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) from ScottGu's blog:

For example, below is a standard type-safe LINQ to SQL VB query that retrieves data from a Northwind database and displays it in a ASP.NET GridView control:

```
Dim Northwind As New NorthwindDataContext
Dim query = From q In Northwind.Products Where p.CategoryID = 2 And p.UnitPrice > 3 Order By p.SupplierID Select p

Gridview1.DataSource = query
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Using the LINQ DynamicQuery library I could re-write the above query expression instead like so

```
Dim Northwind As New NorthwindDataContext
Dim query = Northwind.Products .where("CategoryID=2 And UnitPrice>3") . OrderBy("SupplierId")
Gridview1.DataSource = query
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Notice how the conditional-where clause and sort-orderby clause now take string expressions instead of code expressions.  Because they are late-bound strings I can dynamically construct them.  For example: I could provide UI to an end-user business analyst using my application that enables them to construct queries on their own (including arbitrary conditional clauses).

Comment: Does this work? I get this : Error 28 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OrderBy' can be called with these arguments:
     Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
I can't see 'String' as a parameter option in the .OrderBy clause.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle - It works. I use it in many projects.  Double check that the dynamic.cs is in your project and that you have it referenced properly in your using declarations.

Comment: That is great. I never knew you could do that. That will solve my problem with advanced search query building. Nice one +1

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic Linq is one way to go.

It may be overkill for your scenario.  Consider:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = db.Customers;

if (searchingByName)
{
  query = query.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(someletters));
}
if (searchingById)
{
  query = query.Where(c => c.Id == Id);
}
if (searchingByDonuts)
{
  query = query.Where(c => c.Donuts.Any(d => !d.IsEaten));
}
query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
List<Customer> = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

[Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
var myList = new List<string> { "a","b","c" };
var items = from item in db.Items
            where myList.Contains(item.Name)
            select item;
```

that would create a sql statement like

```
SELECT * FROM Items [t0] where Name IN ('a','b','c')
```

Comment: Interesting concept but a bit confusing