# How do I implement a dynamic 'where' clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to have a dynamic `where` condition.

In the following example:

```
var opportunites =  from opp in oppDC.Opportunities
                    join org in oppDC.Organizations 
                        on opp.OrganizationID equals org.OrgnizationID
                    where opp.Title.StartsWith(title)
                    select new
                    {
                        opp.OpportunityID,
                        opp.Title,
                        opp.PostedBy,
                        opp.Address1,
                        opp.CreatedDate,
                        org.OrganizationName
                    };
```

Some times I have `Title` and sometimes I don't. And also I want to add date in `where` clause dynamically.

For example, like this SQL:

```
string whereClause;
string SQL = whereClause == string.Empty ? 
     "Select * from someTable" : "Select * from someTable" + whereclause
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you aren't actually *writing* [T]SQL here... you are writing C#

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
 var opportunites =  from opp in oppDC.Opportunities
                            join org in oppDC.Organizations on opp.OrganizationID equals org.OrgnizationID
                            select new
                            {
                                opp.OpportunityID,
                                opp.Title,
                                opp.PostedBy,
                                opp.Address1,
                                opp.CreatedDate,
                                org.OrganizationName
                            };

if(condition)
{
   opportunites  = opportunites.Where(opp => opp.Title.StartsWith(title));
}
```

**EDIT:** To answer your question in the comments, yes, you can keep appending to the original Queryable. Remember, this is all lazily executed, so at this point all it's doing it building up the IQueryable so you can keep chaining them together as needed:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
   opportunites  = opportunites.Where(.....);
}

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
   opportunites  = opportunites.Where(.....);
}
```

Comment: Ok fine. Can i append in the where clause. e.g.
if (title != string.Empty)
  opportunites  = opportunites.Where(opp => opp.Title.StartsWith(title));

if (name != string.Empty)
 opportunites  = ..... Append new name in previous where ?????

Comment: @Waheed absolutely.  In fact, the example BFree is showing you is appending the Where clause onto the original IQueryable.  Subsequent Where clauses will have an appending affect as long as you're doing something like opportunities = opportunities.Where(...)

Comment: Way too complex. :-) See my solution that's posted below.

Comment: This seems to work when the Where() contains a condition that uses the "oop" table, but when I use a condition based on a field in the "org" table, it won't compile. It says that the opp table doesn't contain such and such field. Any idea how to work around that?

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically add a where clause to your IQueryable expression like this:

```
var finalQuery = opportunities.Where( x => x.Title == title );
```

and for the date similarly.

However, you will have to wait to create your anonymous type until after you've finished dynamically added your where clauses ***if*** your anonymous type doesn't contain the fields you want to query for in your where clause.

So you might have something that looks like this:

```
var opportunities =  from opp in oppDC.Opportunities
                    join org in oppDC.Organizations on 
                    opp.OrganizationID equals org.OrgnizationID
                    select opp                            

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
   opportunities = opportunities.Where(opp => opp.Title == title);
}

//do the same thing for the date

opportunities = from opp in opportunities
                select new
                        {
                            opp.OpportunityID,
                            opp.Title,
                            opp.PostedBy,
                            opp.Address1,
                            opp.CreatedDate,
                            org.OrganizationName
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause could be done something like

```
//...
where string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? true : opp.Title.StartsWith(title)
//...
```

Dynamically returning records I don't think is possible in LINQ since it needs to be able to create a consistent AnonymousType (in the background)

Comment: You'd need to check it, but that may result in very poorly performing TSQL (if it takes the test all the way to the database)

Comment: Good point - I figured since it delayed execution it might not bother.

Answer (score 1):

Because queries are composable, you can just build the query in steps.

```
var query = table.Selec(row => row.Foo);

if (someCondition)
{
    query = query.Where(item => anotherCondition(item));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance all possible where queries like in the SQL example you have given you can write the query like this

```
from item in Items
where param == null ? true : ni.Prop == param
select item;
```

if you don't know all possible where clauses in advance you can add where dymically for example like this:

```
query = query.Where(item => item.ID != param);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following questions and answers address this quite well:

> [Dynamic where clause in LINQ - with column names available at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234439/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq-with-column-names-available-at-runtime)
>   [Is there a pattern using Linq to dynamically create a filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879/is-there-a-pattern-using-linq-to-dynamically-create-a-filter)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for creating a dynamic where clause in LINQ and came across a very beautifull solution on the web which uses ExpressionBuilder in C#.

I am posting it here since none of the above solution uses this approach. It helped me. Hope it helps you too
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq