# Equivalent to SQL IN clause

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've got an entity called new_trexmail with a string attribute called new_contextline.

I'm trying to get a list of entities where new_contextlineis in a defined list.

The following code fails with the error : `NotSupportedException: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.`

```
string[] test = new[]{"aaa", "hhh"};

var query = from n in New_trexmailSet
            where test.Contains(n.New_contextline)
            select n;
```

I understand why this error is being thrown but I'm wondering if it's possible to do the equiavalent of an IN clause using XRM.

If it is possible then how do I go about getting XRM to execute `SELECT * FROM new_trexmail WHERE new_contextline in ('aaa', 'hhh')`?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the (longer than desired) [list of LINQ limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations), particularly the limitation on the `where` clause:

> The left side of the clause must be an attribute name and the right
>   side of the clause must be a value. You cannot set the left side to a
>   constant. Both the sides of the clause cannot be constants. Supports
>   the String functions Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith, and Equals.

So since `test` isn't a CRM attribute, you can't call `Contains` on it. However, one way around this is to use "[Dynamic Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30887/684271)" as developed by ScottGu and as demonstrated below:

```
//must include the below using statements
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Linq.Dynamic;

var trexmailSet = New_trexmailSet;

string[] test = new[] { "aaa", "hhh" };

string whereClause = "";

foreach (string name in test)
{
    whereClause += string.Format("new_contextline = \"{0}\" OR ", name);
}

trexmailSet = trexmailSet.Where(whereClause.Substring(0, whereClause.Length - 4));

var query = from n in trexmailSet
            select n;
```

Comment: That does the job! I wasn't aware of that library, it looks pretty useful. Thanks very much.