# Dynamics CRM 2011 LinQ to Find New Records

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a bunch of custom entity records in a List (which comes from a csv file).
What is the best way to check which records are new and create those that are?
The equality check is based on a single text field in this case, but I need to do the same thing elsewhere where the equality check is based on a lookup and 2 text fields.

For arguments sake lets say I was inserting Account records, this is what I currently have:

```c#
    private void CreateAccounts()
    {
        var list = this.GetAccounts(); // get the list of Accounts, some may be new
        IEnumerable<string> existingAccounts = linq.AccountSet.Select(account => account.AccountNumber); // get all Account numbers in CRM, linq is a serviceContextName variable
        var newAccounts = list.Where(account => !existingAccounts.Contains(account.AccountNumber)); // Account numbers not in CRM
        foreach (var accountNumber in newAccounts) // go through the new list again and get all the Account info
        {
            var account = newAccounts.Where(newAccount => newAccount.AccountNumber.Equals(accountNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
            service.Create(account);
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I seem to be iterating through lists too many times, but it must be better than querying CRM multiple times:

```c#
foreach (var account in list) 
        {
            // is this Account already in CRM
            // if not create the Account
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method seems a bit backwards (get everything out of CRM, then compare it to what you have locally), but it may not be too bad depending on how many accounts you have ie < 5000.

For your simple example, you should be able to apply a [where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881302/equivalent-to-sql-in-clause) statement.

Joining on multiple fields is a little more tricky.  If you are running CRM > R12, you should be able to use the [ExecuteMultipleRequests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx), creating a seperate request for each item in your list, and then batching them all up, so there is one big request "over the wire" to CRM.